# Is it possible to make rounded image (via mask) on Multibutton (Codename One)

Tags: java, codenameone

I have an `InfiniteScrollAdapter` in which I use `Multibutton` to display a list featuring a photo and its description.

It works well but I need to make the photo rounded. That's why I got inspired by [the official guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/graphics.html) on image masking. Unfortunately what I get is only a black round. Here is the code I used:

```
MultiButton[] cmps = new MultiButton[reports.size()];
for (int iter = 0; iter < reports.size(); iter++) {
    Report currentReport = reports.get(iter);
    if (currentReport == null) {
        InfiniteScrollAdapter.addMoreComponents(this.getContentPane(), new Component[0], false);
        return;
    }

    String photoFilenameInStorage = Report.getFilename(currentReport.getPhotoPath());
    Image reportImage = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, photoFilenameInStorage, currentReport.getPhotoPath(), URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL );
    int w = reportImage.getWidth();
    int h = reportImage.getHeight();

    // Generates a mask to make the image round
    Image maskImage = Image.createImage(w, h, 0xff000000);
    Graphics g = maskImage.getGraphics();
    g.setAntiAliased(true);
    g.setColor(0xFFFFFF);
    g.fillArc(0, 0, w, h, 0, 360);

    Object mask = maskImage.createMask();

    Image maskedImage = reportImage.applyMask(mask);

    String summary = currentReport.getLocation();                        
    cmps[iter] = new MultiButton(summary);
    // Only shows a black filled circle!
    cmps[iter].setIcon(maskedImage);
} 

InfiniteScrollAdapter.addMoreComponents(this.getContentPane(), cmps, true);
```

What I've noticed is that all examples I could find about the rounded image in CN1 dealt with `Label`. Is it possible to apply a mask on a `MultiButton` in Codename One? If so, how can I do that?

Any help appreciated,

**Summary after reading the answers and comments 2017-02-16**

I have had hard time to figure out why @Diamond's answer did work and not mine although I did follow @Shai's guide on masking to get rounded images. So I write the outcome of my findings in case other newbies at CN1 came across this issue. Thnaks again to @Diamond for his great explanations that helped a lot!

First of all, the round mask introduced above is working since it yields a black round. Indeed by the time where the mask is applied the `reportImage` has not been downloaded yet [since quoting from the javadoc](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/URLImage.html)

> By default an image is fetched lazily as it is asked for by the GUI unless the fetch() method is invoked in which case the IO code is executed immediately.

Consequently `reportImage` is still as black as the placeholder was defined. By the way this is why @Diamond suggested to define a **round placeholder** with a nice color to be shown before the actual (round) image gets available (see the first `cmps[iter].setIcon(placeholder)` call in his answer).

And the URLImage will only be actually downloaded when the `InfiniteScrollAdapter` needs and fetches the image.That's why @Diamond wraps

So as a conclusion the code above cannot work in an `InfiniteScrollAdapter` and after all my trials I tend to think that the only way to achieve what I wanted to do is the code @Diamond wrote with @Shai's suggestion.

**Please note that with if the downloaded picture is a PNG @Diamond's round mask adapter does not seem to work anymore => the resulting image is only rounded if the PNG is converted as JPEG**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, Multibutton icon is a Label component which you can get by calling

```
cmps[iter].getIconComponent()
```

**Edit:**

Based on Shai's comment, your code should become something like this...

**Round Mask Adapter:**

```
private final URLImage.ImageAdapter RESIZE_SCALE_WITH_ROUND_MASK = new URLImage.ImageAdapter() {
    @Override
    public EncodedImage adaptImage(EncodedImage downloadedImage, EncodedImage placeholderImage) {
        Image tmp = downloadedImage.scaledLargerRatio(placeholderImage.getWidth(), placeholderImage.getHeight());
        if (tmp.getWidth() > placeholderImage.getWidth()) {
            int diff = tmp.getWidth() - placeholderImage.getWidth();
            int x = diff / 2;
            tmp = tmp.subImage(x, 0, placeholderImage.getWidth(), placeholderImage.getHeight(), true);
        } else if (tmp.getHeight() > placeholderImage.getHeight()) {
            int diff = tmp.getHeight() - placeholderImage.getHeight();
            int y = diff / 2;
            tmp = tmp.subImage(0, y, Math.min(placeholderImage.getWidth(), tmp.getWidth()),
                    Math.min(placeholderImage.getHeight(), tmp.getHeight()), true);
        }
        Image roundMask = Image.createImage(tmp.getWidth(), tmp.getHeight(), 0xff000000);
        Graphics gr = roundMask.getGraphics();
        gr.setColor(0xffffff);

        gr.fillArc(0, 0, tmp.getWidth(), tmp.getHeight(), 0, 360);
        Object mask = roundMask.createMask();
        tmp = tmp.applyMask(mask);
        return EncodedImage.createFromImage(tmp, false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAsyncAdapter() {
        return true;
    }
};
```

**Code Improvement:**

```
//Placeholder image

int size = Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(20);
Image placeholder = Image.createImage(size, size, 0xbfc9d2);
Graphics g = placeholder.getGraphics();
g.setAntiAliased(true);
g.setColor(0xbfc9d2);
g.fillArc(0, 0, size, size, 0, 360);

MultiButton[] cmps = new MultiButton[reports.size()];
for (int iter = 0; iter < reports.size(); iter++) {
    Report currentReport = reports.get(iter);
    if (currentReport == null) {
        InfiniteScrollAdapter.addMoreComponents(this.getContentPane(), new Component[0], false);
        return;
    }

    String photoFilenameInStorage = Report.getFilename(currentReport.getPhotoPath());

    String summary = currentReport.getLocation();
    cmps[iter] = new MultiButton(summary);
    // Only shows a black filled circle!
    cmps[iter].setIcon(placeholder);

    Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
       cmps[iter].setIcon( URLImage.createToStorage(cmps[iter].getIcon(), photoFilenameInStorage, currentReport.getPhotoPath(), RESIZE_SCALE_WITH_ROUND_CORNER_MASK));
       cmps[iter].getParent().revalidate();
    });
}
InfiniteScrollAdapter.addMoreComponents(this.getContentPane(), cmps, true);
```

Comment: Correct. I'd also like to add that it would be faster to round the image in advance (e.g. like `URLImage` does) which will make the app stutter less.

Comment: Thanks @Diamond! However I can't get it work, so I have to better understand. So if I may ask you some more questins about your code : 1) why are you calling `setIcon` before the `getIconComponent` call ? 2) Moreover what's the purpose of encapsulating the `getIconComponent` within a `callSerially` . 3) And finally why are you calling `revalidate` whereas the component `cmps` has not been added ?

Comment: To be more accurate on what does not work, I think the mask does not work because the pictures appear not rounded (but not black anymore, so that's already a change). I will dive into your code to better understand it!

Comment: Here is how it works: The first `setIcon()` sets all the MultiButtons' icons to a placeholder image as they are being created and added to a container. The second `setIcon()` is called inside `callSerially()` which delays fetching of the remote icons until the MultiButton is visible. This makes continuous scrolling and fetching seamless. `callSerially` delays execution until other tasks are done; In this case, the task is creating and adding components to the InfiniteContainer.

Comment: I have modified the code a bit to remove `getIconComponent()` which I feel is unnecessary.

Comment: Just so you know, your placeholder image should be round. See added code.

Comment: To prevent re-using of old downloaded images, clear the images in your `.cn1` folder.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot Diamond for those explanations! The .cn1 folder cleaning should do the trick, I forgot this cache although this old UrlImage persistence issue had already happened to me several times! I'll keep you posted!

Comment: @Diamond I edited my question and -based on your answers and comments- added the reason why my code lead to black rounds!