# Why is the width of my placeholder not abode in URLImage (Codename One)

Tags: codenameone

My app features a form with 2 images. The first one is downloaded and rounded via an `ImageAdapter` on the fly and the second one is from the theme. They are applied to a `Button` and laid next to each other as shown below :

[image: Part of app layout]

**In my Form**

The placeholder in my form is defined as :

```
int imageWidth = (int) (Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth() / 2.5);
EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(Image.createImage(
            imageWidth,
            imageWidth,
            ParametresGeneraux.accentColor), true);
```

The image I apply on the button is created like this :

```
reportImage = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder,
            Report.getFilename(chosenReport.getPhotoPath()),
            chosenReport.getPhotoPath(),
            ParametresGeneraux.RESIZE_SCALE_WITH_ROUND_MASK
    );
```

Then I do just afterwards

```
        System.err.println("The placeholder in FORM has a width of " + placeholder.getWidth()); // 432
```

I get a width of 432 for the placeholder from within the FORM.

**However from the ImageAdapter**

```
public final static URLImage.ImageAdapter RESIZE_SCALE_WITH_ROUND_MASK =   new URLImage.ImageAdapter() {
    @Override
    public EncodedImage adaptImage(EncodedImage downloadedImage, EncodedImage placeholderImage) {
        System.err.println("The placeholder in the ImageAdapter has a width of " + placeholderImage.getWidth());
       // ...
    }
});
```

The placeholder width I get from within the `ImageAdapter` is different with a value of 200.

Where should I look at for a mistake, since the placeholder widths should be the same in both methods, shouldn't they ?

**Edit 2017-02-23 : Important note**
Before showing this form, the involved image has already been downloaded a first time in another form with a different size. And actually the message from the ImageAdapter (see `System.err()`) is not triggered. I overflew this because many images are loaded. See my answer for the continuation.

Any hint appreciated,

Regards

Comment: Are you using GridLayout above?

Comment: No I am not. The Buttons are added later (after this call) via `this.add(BorderLayout.centerCenter(BoxLayout.encloseX(reportImageButton, minimapButton))); ` with the form in Y-BoxLayout

Comment: Laying it alone does not change `this.add(BorderLayout.centerCenter(reportImageButton));` . The width still differs.

Comment: I hope you're aware that you are using `roundPlaceholder` on your URLImage and not `placeholder`...the sizes may differ.

Comment: That was a mistake when I pasted the code. I changed it.

Comment: What simulated device are you testing with?

Comment: I have tested it on Nexus5, GoogleNexus7, iphone5_OS7 with the same behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @Diamond, your questions helped! I'll write the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually it appeared that the

`System.err.println("The placeholder in the ImageAdapter has a width of " + placeholderImage.getWidth());`

displayed in the console was not from the `ImageAdapter` call in this form but from the previous form which actually downloaded and showed the same image a first time.

So the second time I call `URLImage.createToStorage()` with the same internal name (see `Report.getFilename(chosenReport.getPhotoPath())` in my question) as the file has already been downloaded and is present in cache, it is not downloaded again as written in the [doc](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/image-from-url-made-easy.html) :

> Notice that the image that will be saved is the scaled image, which means you will have very little overhead in downloading images that are the wrong size although you will get some artifacts.

Finally if I changed the internal name, and then even though the Image gets downloaded it scales perfectly :

[image]

Comment: In addition to this, always clear your `.cn1` storage folder at your computer user HomePath when debugging URLImage.

Comment: Right, I added a method to do that (since your [answer from here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42240532/6351897) indeed!). 
`if (Display.getInstance().isSimulator()) {
            String [] files  = Storage.getInstance().listEntries();
            for (String f : files ){
                if (f.endsWith("jpg")){
                    Storage.getInstance().deleteStorageFile(f);
                    System.out.println("The following image has been deleted " + f);
                }
            }
            System.err.println("Images have been successfully cleared on simulator!");
        }`